# Cartesian coordinates in New York City from angles on the earth.

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, trigonometry

I am in the following situation:

I have a bunch of points $(r_i)$ on the sphere given by their angles $(\theta,\varphi).$ The radius $R$ of the sphere is also known.

The points are all in one part of the sphere. Coordinates of sights in NYC might be a good example.

So now rather than talking the positions in $(\theta,\varphi)$, I would like to find a local cartesian coordinate system such that I can express my coordinates as $(x_i,y_i)$.

In particular, if I take the euclidean distance between my points, then this should correspond to the actual distance.

I understand how to go from $(\theta,\varphi)$ to $(x,y,z)$ on the entire sphere, but here I would like to have a local chart and omit one of the three coordinates.

Comment: Removing a coordinate sounds like a projection to me. The question would be how to choose a plane to project onto, such that the errors from curved sphere to flat plane are minimal.

Comment: As radius is fixed, then you already have plane $(\theta,\varphi)$ with 2 cartesian coordinates. Why you need some other?

Comment: @zkutch If I have two points $(\theta_1,\varphi_1)$ and $(\theta_2,\varphi_2)$ then $\sqrt{(\theta_1-\theta_2)^2+ (\varphi_1-\varphi_2)^2}$ is not the actual distance between the points, even if they are close on the sphere. Therefore, this coordinate system does not satisfy this requirement.

Comment: How big is the local region, and how accurate do you want the distance to be? You might find this recent related question helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4178653/207316

Comment: If you need more accuracy than a spherical Earth model gives, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Comment: @PM2Ring the leading order taylor expansion should be the correct distance and the area I am considering is something like the city of New York. One might argue that for distances there, the curvature of the earth is negligible

Comment: Sure, you can use a plane approximation on that distance scale. You just need to scale the longitudinal distance appropriately. It's simple to do that if we assume the Earth is a sphere, as in the question I previously linked. You can divide the longitudinal distance by $\cos(\varphi)$, where $\varphi$ is the usual (geodetic) latitude. But you get better accuracy if you use an ellipsoidal model, because the length of a parallel of latitude isn't exactly $2\pi R \cos(\varphi)$, where $R$ is the mean radius of the Earth.

Comment: IIRC, there does not exist a coordinate system on even a small region of a sphere in which spherical distance takes exactly the form of Cartesian distance. That's an immediate consequence of Gauss's _Theorema Egregium_. There does, however, exist an explicit (but slightly messy) trigonometric formula for spherical distance in terms of latitude and longitude.

Comment: See also this related answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2611287/255730

Comment: There are many ways to solve your problem: orthographic projection onto a plane tangent to the Earth, stereographic projection, central projections onto various cylinders, central projection onto a cone, and projections by mathematical formula without such physical analogues, such as Mercator projection or the projection mentioned in the previous comment. All give good approximations of distance over a small area, often while preserving some other property exactly.